# Passing in the adress of a buffer and prompt message in the same subroutine

Tags: assembly, mips

hello im working on this assignment and it asks me to "Write a subroutine that prompts for a string. Pass the address of the input buffer in $a0, the size of the
input buffer in $a1 and the address of the prompt message in $a2." and we are told to use Stack Based Linkage. my confusion is the use of the $a0 register, in MIPS the system call code for printing as string involves using $a0 but for this particular subroutine we are using the $a0 register in order to pass in the input buffer, which would in fact be used when using system call 8, which reads a string from the user and does in fact need $a0 for the input buffer address and $a1 for the size of the input buffer.

in the subroutine ive tried to just use the "MOVE" macro to move $a0 (input buffer size) into $s0 and then move $a2 into $a0 to perform the prompting and then move $s0 back into $a0 to use for when i need to read the input from the user. but i get memory bounds errors in QTSpim

edit: forgot to add my code

```
    .text
    .globl main
    
main:   la  $a0, str1           # prompting for two different strings
    li  $a1, 100
    la  $a2, prmpt1
    jal prompt
    nop
    la  $a0, str2
    li  $a1, 100
    la  $a2, prmpt2
    jal prompt
    nop

    
    li  $v0, 10
    syscall
    
prompt: 
    
    move    $s0, $a0    # save passed $a0
    
    li  $v0, 4      # print prompt
    move    $a0, $a2
    syscall
    move    $a0, $s0
    li  $v0, 8      # read input
    syscall
    jr  $ra
    nop




    .data
    
str1:   .space 120
str2:   .space 120

prmpt1: .asciiz "enter the first string : \n"
prmpt2: .asciiz "enter the second string : \n"
```

Comment: Yes, moving it away and back is the general idea. The error is unrelated. Use the simulator to verify everything is as it should be. [edit] the question to include your code.

Comment: @Jester edited to include my code, can you confirm? i fixed the error i was having but just wanted to confirm if this would be accurate to what the question would be asking, thanks

Comment: Yes, you have the right idea, and that will work here.  The only issue is that `$s0` is a call-preserved register, so using it without preserving and restoring is a violation of the calling convention, so bad for real programs.

Comment: @ErikEidt They can just use `$t0` and it'll be fine, right?

Comment: @puppydrum64, yes, `$t0` will survive syscalls (but it won't necessarily survive a regular function call).